# here.com map class MapLabeledMarker is Decprecated?

Tags: here-api

I am using latest here.com map library which was modified on 11-02-2016. To this jar file the class MapLabeledMarker is not present whether is it deprecated? or I have to make use some other version library to use above class. Answers are much appreciated.

com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapLabeledMarker ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [Starter](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-intro.html) or [Premium](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-intro.html) version of the HERE SDK for Android? The **Starter** version does not contain `MapLabeledMarker`, it is only available in the **Premium** version.

More info on HERE SDK versions: https://developer.here.com/plans/mobile-sdk

Comment: I changed library to Premium SDK. Now the class can be access.